# Rails error - ActionController::UrlGenerationError in BookingsController (Create action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an events app using rails and I've run into the error above at the end of the booking confirmation process. This is the full error - 
[image: Full error]

And this is my controller code -

**Bookings Controller**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!



    def new

        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = Booking.new(params[:booking])
        @booking.user = current_user



    end

    def create

        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user


            if 
                @booking.booking
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end

            if @event.is_free?
                @booking.save(booking_params)
            end
    end

    def show
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end


    def update

        if @booking.update(booking_params)
            redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking) , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end




    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :booking_number, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
    end






end
```

I'm trying to implement code to handle both free and paid events/bookings. The event side is fine but handling free bookings has proved troublesome. This is the Booking model code -

**Booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user


  before_create :set_booking_number 

     validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
     validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
     validates :quantity, :total_amount, :booking_number, presence: true

  def set_booking_number
    self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
  end



    def booking
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        #self.valid?


        if self.event.is_free?

            self.total_amount = 0
        else



            begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
              self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                  end
            end 
        #end
  end
end
```

This issue arose following the inclusion of the validations - the problem has been trying to implement validations that apply to paid events but not free.

Any assistance with the above error would be appreciated.

Comment: This error is unrelated to model. So, adding/removing validations won't affect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking)
```

with

```
redirect_to event_booking_path(id: @booking.id, event_id: @event.id)
```

**UPDATE**

I believe the error is because `@booking.id` is evaluating to `nil`. It would happen is `@booking` is not saved to db (still a new record). In you model method `booking`, inside `if` block, you are just setting an attribute, but not saving the object. So, calling `save!` inside `if` block after setting the attribute should fix this.

```
def booking
  if self.event.is_free?
    self.total_amount = 0
    save!
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: No, that hasn't changed anything. I think event.id should be @event.event_id - when I use that I get 'undefined method' error for event_id.

Comment: The reason I've included the model is - I changed the model and the code broke. I hadn't changed the controller and previously this was working, so not sure why that is.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error as mentioned in the question? If yes, please post the output of `rake routes | grep bookings`

Comment: It's too long to post in entirety, this is for the show route - event_booking GET      /events/:event_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#show

Comment: Thanks for this - I was also missing save! for the paid code too - just checked. I've also adjusted the validations. All works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper route

Rails is expecting `:id` instead of `:event_id`

so, if you are using restful routes

use the url as `booking_path(7)` instead of `booking_path(event_id: 7)`

or change your route to

```
get 'bookings/:event_id', to: 'bookings#show'
```

Comment: I've tried the route change and that hasn't changed anything. I'm not sure what you mean for the restful routes method - sorry for sounding daft but where does the number 7 come from?

Comment: If this is a params issue - do I need to change any of the arguments in the create method?